# Error getting connection to database from pool using in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, database-connection, connection-pooling

well I have a pretty awkward situation. I have a working database managers class, which works when I run it on the desktop version of it (Swing GUI), however, when I run the same class on the servlet, I get a strange error, that it can't get the connection. I am using database pooling for optimisation.

So the error looks as follows:

```
Error in Database Connection: Error getting connection to database - java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://isd.ktu.lt:1433;DatabaseName=LN2012_bakDB2
```

And the class with the methods involved looks like this:

```
    package Core;

import DataTypes.Parameters;
import Interfaces.OutputInterface;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDriver;
import org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool;

/**
 *
 * @author arturas
 */
public class DatabaseConnection {

    String specificError = "Error in Database Connection: ";
    OutputInterface gui = null;
    boolean allowOutput = true;
    GenericObjectPool connectionPool;
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory;
    PoolingDriver driver;
    Connection con = null;

    public DatabaseConnection(Parameters params) {                

        // parameters and the output                
        this.gui = params.getGui();

        // activate database pool
        connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool(null);
        connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(params.getDbAdr(), params.getDbUser(), params.getDbPass());
        poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, connectionPool, null, null, false, true);
        driver = new PoolingDriver();
        driver.registerPool("GenTreeDatabase", connectionPool);        
    }

    public void openConn() {
        if (allowOutput) gui.print("Getting connection to database");
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:GenTreeDatabase");
            if (con != null) {
                if (allowOutput) gui.print("Connection to database was successful");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            gui.err(specificError + "Error getting connection to database - " + ex);
        }
    }

    public void closeConn() {
        try {
            con.close();
            if (allowOutput) {
                gui.print("Connection to database closed successfully");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            gui.err(specificError + ex);
        }
    }
```

The error appears when the try in method openConn is called.
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: You need to add the database driver jar in your classpath. Which RDBMS  r u using?

Comment: right which rdbms are you using ? and the IDE too you r using

Comment: @shareef The RDBMS is MS SQL Server, the Server for the servlet is Tomcat, the IDE is Netbeans 7.12. The Database pooling driver is apache commons dbcp 1.4 and apache commons pool 1.6

Comment: which version of MS SQL Server please ?

Comment: what do you mean "when I run the same class on the servlet" ? and the error you provided does not have a line number associated with it can you give us the error line and the class along with it

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because there is no drivers in your classpath. Probably in your desktop application there were. You need to put driver's `.jar` file into your servlet container's global classpath or in your application classpath and it should work.

I prefer adding driver's jar into server global classpath, because there can be more than one application which will use the same `.jar` file to load drivers.

Comment: \ Matulionis I see. Could you give me some tips on how to do that in apache tomcat 7 (In Netbeans 7.12)?

Comment: Netbeans has nothing to do with this, put the driver's jar file into tomcat's library directory. Lets say you have tomcat installed in C:\Servers\tomcat-7. Go to that directory and put the appropriate jar into \lib folder. Full directory: C:\Servers\tomcat-7\lib. Restart tomcat and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

make sure of this

1) you should make sure that .jar library is compatabile with RDMS you are using 
2) that you included the .jar for connection in your netbeans in

```
projectproperties-->libraries
```

3)copy the .jar into
 `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 6.0.26\lib`

and this is important

if you dont have the driver in location you get not found error but 
you get no suitable so i think the version must be incompatible so what version of sql server are you using...

Comment: The database is running on MS SQL Server 2008. The jar is sqljdbc4.jar recently downloaded from MS website. The libs seem to be in places, though it still does seem to not work. Hmm

Comment: I assume that the jar is compatible, because it runs in the Swing GUI version of the application?

Comment: Yes, you right. But when you added the jar to tomcat classpath did you restart the server?

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis Yeah, since NetBeans stops tomcat when you close it, I did that and started it later again.

Comment: Hmm. Can you try to deploy your application not using netbeans? Just to make sure that netbeans has nothing to do with it. Make a .war file of your application using clean and build in netbeans, than start tomcat manually from tomcat-install-dir\bin\startup.bat. Open browser localhost:<yourPort>/manager/html deploy your application and check in tomcat logs if the error occurs.